# npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists while creating the Docker image for Node project

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created one node.js project called simpleWeb. The project contains package.json and index.js.

index.js

```js
    const express = require('express');
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('How are you doing');
    });
    
    app.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port 8080');
    });
```

package.json

```json
    {
        "dependencies": {
          "express": "*"
        },
        "scripts": {
          "start": "node index.js"
        }
      }
```

I have also created one Dockerfile to create the docker image for my node.js project.

Dockerfile

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

# Install some dependencies 
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

# Default command
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

While I am tried to build the docker image using "docker build ." command it is throwing below error.

Error Logs

```
simpleweb » docker build .                                                    ~/Desktop/jaypal/Docker and Kubernatise/simpleweb
[+] Building 16.9s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                                               8.7s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 418B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine@sha256:5b91260f78485bfd4a1614f1afa9afd59920e4c35047ed1c2b8cde4f239dd79b         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] COPY ./ ./                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN npm install                                                                                              8.0s
------
 > [3/3] RUN npm install:
#8 7.958 npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists
#8 7.969
#8 7.970 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 7.970 npm ERR!     **/root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-24T16_48_44_443Z-debug.log**
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
```

The log file above it is providing one path "/root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-24T16_48_44_443Z-debug.log" where I can find the full logs.

But, The above file is not present on my local machine.

I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: Do not change a previously asked question so it becomes a new question with a totally different problem. The answers previously given now don't answer your changed question. Please create a new question when you have a new problem.

Comment: from node version > 14 you need to specify `WORKDIR` in docker file. if you don't want to mention `WORKDIR` in docker file. use node version <= 14

Comment: About the part that you said "The above file is not present on my local machine", note that you should open the log file in your container, not on your local machine. You can do so by running container via `docker run -it node:alpine sh` which gives you a shell inside a running container out of image `node:alpine`. Then, execute `npm install` in that shell which end up in the very same error and eventually access the aforementioned log file.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

This issue is happening due to changes in NodeJS starting with version 15. When no `WORKDIR` is specified, `npm install` is executed in the root directory of the container, which is resulting in this error. Executing the `npm install` in a project directory of the container specified by `WORKDIR` resolves the issue.

Use the following `Dockerfile`:

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

#Install some dependencies

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./ /usr/app
RUN npm install

# Set up a default command
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

Comment: Please make sure to explain why an answer works, so other people can adapt for their own usecases.

Comment: This issue is happening due to changes in nodejs starting version 15. When no WORKDIR is specified, npm install is executed in the root directory of the container, which is resulting in this error. Executing the npm install from within a project directory in the container resolves the issue.

Comment: so what was the previous place where this was stored? does it matter?

Comment: i'm still kinda confused, isn't the root of the container the "/"? COPY ./ ./ should work, because we are copying the project files to the root dir "/"

Comment: Please can you explain where is located the Dockerfile?

Comment: The problem is my image isn't alpine it's ubuntu.

Comment: It's 2023 I don't think this solution is valid anymore. It is still not working despite WORKDIR specified

Comment: The solution is working, although the question is why? it would be better if someone describe it a little more.

Comment: Agree. Solution worked for me only when I replaced COPY ./ ./ to COPY ./ /app like not the root. No idea why ./ ./ is not working.

Answer (score 42):

## Global install

In the event you're wanting to install a package globally outside of working directory with a `package.json`, you should use the `-g` flag.

```
npm install -g <pkg>
```

This error may trigger if the CI software you're using like `semantic-release` is built in node and you attempt to install it outside of a working directory.

Answer (score 30):

The correct answer is basically right, but when I tried it still didn't work. Here's why:

`WORKDIR` specifies the context to the `COPY` that follows it. Having already specified the context in `./usr/app` it is wrong to ask to copy from `./` (the directory you are working in) to `./usr/app` as this produces the following structure in the container: `./usr/app/usr/app`.

As a result `CMD ["npm", "start"]`, which is followed where specified by `WORKDIR` (`./usr/app`) does not find the `package.json`.

I suggest using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: he has used /usr/app not ./usr/app. In the later case u end up creating duplicate sub dirs

Comment: Why would you run npm i after copying all the source files, this won't cache? I suggest you read up on Docker layers and why you should order layers from least often changed to most often changed

Answer (score 6):

You should specify the WORKDIR prior to COPY instruction in order to ensure the execution of npm install inside the directory where all your application files are there. Here is how you can complete this:

```
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install some dependencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
```

Note that you can **simply** "COPY ./ (current local directory) ./ (container directory which is now /usr/app thanks to the WORKDIR instruction)" **instead** of "COPY ./ /usr/app"

Now the good reason to use WORKDIR instruction is that you avoid mixing your application files and directories with the root file system of the container (to avoid overriding file system directories in case you have similar directories labels on your application directories)

One more thing. It is a good practice to segment a bit your configuration so that when you make a change for example in your index.js (so then you need to rebuild your image), you will not need to run "npm install" while the package.json has not been modified.

Your application is very basic, but think of a big applications where "npm install" should take several minutes.

In order to make use of caching process of Docker, you can segment your configuration as follows:

```
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install some dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
```

This instructs Docker to cache the first COPY and RUN commands when package.json is not touched. So when you change for instance the index.js, and you rebuild your image, Docker will use cache of the previous instructions (first COPY and RUN) and start executing the second COPY. This makes your rebuild much quicker.

Example for image rebuild:

```
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /usr/app                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY ./package.json ./                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [5/5] COPY ./ ./
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but for projects not wanting to create a Dockerfile for the installer, it is also possible to run the installer from an [Ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers) container. This gives full access to the Node CLI, without having to install it on the host machine.

The command assumes it is run from the root of the project and there is a package.json file present. The `-v $(pwd):/app` option mounts the current working directory to the /app folder in the container, synchronizing the installed files back to the host directory. The `-w /app` option sets the work directory of the image as the /app folder. The `--loglevel=verbose` option causes the output of install command to be verbose. More options can be found on the [official Node docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) page.

```sh
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app node npm install --loglevel=verbose
```

Personally I use  a Makefile to store several Ephemeral container commands that are faster to run separate from the build process. But of course, anything is possible :)

Answer (score 4):

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install some dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

# Default command
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

1.This is also write if you change any of your index file and  docker build and docker run it automatically change your new changes to your browser output

Answer (score 4):

specifying working directory as below inside Dockerfile will work:

```
WORKDIR '/app'
```

make sure to use --build in your docker-compose command to build from Dockerfile again:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: This is hugely underrated.  The node image doesn't do "npm install" in the root directory, so you just need a different directory.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can change node version.Besides don't forget WORKDIR

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: WORKDIR in crucial for this error

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm init` and `npm install express` to create package.json file

Comment: This answer is not that bad, because npm install needs the package.json. Unless, of course, you use the -g flag.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of [Col](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8235572/col), you could also do the following in your viewmodel:

```
public class IndexVM() {

   @AfterCompose
   public void doAfterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.COMPONENT) Component c) {
       Window wizard = (Window) c;
       Label label = (Label) c.getFellow("lblName");
       ....
   }
}
```

In doing so, you actually have access to the label object and can perform all sorts of tasks with it (label.setValue(), label.getValue(), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The above-given solutions didn't work for me, I have changed the node image in my  from `node:alpine` to `node:12.18.1` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On current latest `node:alpine3.13` it's just enough to copy the content of root folder into container's root folder with `COPY ./ ./`, while omitting the `WORKDIR` command. But as a practical solution I would recommend:

`WORKDIR /usr/app` - *it goes by convention among developers to put project into separate folder* 
`COPY ./package.json ./` - *here we copy only package.json file in order to avoid rebuilds from npm*
`RUN npm install`
`COPY ./ ./` - *here we copy all the files (remember to create .dockerignore file in the root dir to avoid copying your node_modules folder)*

Answer (score 0):

We also have a similar issue, So I replaced my npm with 'yarn' it worked quit well. here is the sample code.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1
#install bash
RUN apk --update add bash zip yaml-dev
RUN apk add --update nodejs yarn build-base postgresql-dev gcc python3- 
dev musl-dev libffi-dev
RUN yarn config set prefix ~/.yarn



#install serverless
RUN yarn global add serverless@2.49.0 --prefix /usr/local && \
yarn global add serverless-pseudo-parameters@2.4.0 && \
yarn global add serverless-python-requirements@4.3.0


RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY requirements-test.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements-test.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["bash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to specify node version less than 15.

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:14

# Install some dependencies 
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

# Default command
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

That was my problem: There is no package.json
Added then fixed