# While building a docker files i'm getting error executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build an image of my node application but upon execution it shows the error.

```bash
PS C:\Users\vallabh\Desktop\visits> docker build .
[+] Building 3.8s (5/5) FINISHED

[internal] load build definition from Dorkerfile
=> transferring Dockerfile! 31B
=> [internal] load .dockerignore
=> => Transferring context: 2B 
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine 
=> CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine@sha256 :0677e437543016F6cb058d92792a14e5eb84348e3d5b4
> ERROR [2/2] RUN npm install:
```

The exact error is:

```
------
 > [2/2] RUN npm install:
#5 1.745 npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists
#5 1.748
#5 1.748 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#5 1.748 npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-28T07_47_19_509Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
PS C:\Users\vallabh\Desktop\visits> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1D
```

How can I avoid this `npm install` error?

For illustration:

[image: error]

Answer (score 6):

Including the node version in the Dockerfile worked for me:

```
FROM node:19.5.0-alpine
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I am using node 16: `FROM node:16.16.0-alpine`

Answer (score 2):

Check first if you have a similar issue [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65443098/6309):

> This issue is happening due to changes in NodeJS starting with version 15.
>
> When no `WORKDIR` is specified, `npm install` is executed in the root directory of the container, which is resulting in this error.
>
> Executing the `npm install` in a project directory of the container specified by `WORKDIR` resolves the issue.

In your case, make sure to set `WORKDIR` to where your node app resides in your image that you are building.

Comment: I have the same issue but I have a WORKDIR ```WORKDIR /app```, do  you know what I can try ?

Comment: @VersifiXion Check the pwd (`RUN pwd`) when you are executing `npm install` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm stuck at docker build step, I can't build the image, how should I use pwd there please ?

Comment: @VersifiXion That would merit its own question then, in which you can explain what image you are using, what Dockerfile and what you have tried.

Comment: Ok I just made a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75202024/cant-build-an-image-from-dockerfile-executor-failed-running-bin-sh-c-npm-in

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, then I discovered that it is different architecture, since my node_module directory was copied from my mac M1 machine to alpine base image, this caused a problem, I have just excluded the copy of node_modules when copying from dev directory to image. using copy command.

**So simply** the solution is to ignore copying node_modules directory:

1. Create a file in the dev directory called **.dockerignore** this works the same way in .gitignore
2. Add the following line to it

`node_modules`

This solved my issue and  image was built successfully

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and none of the above answers helped, the solution that me in this case was-

1. Remove node modules folder

   sudo rm -r node_modules
2. install node modules again

   npm i
3. re-run the docker start command

   docker-compose up --build

Edit: Since, I have spent good amount of time working with this issue, let me explain you what the actual problem is, sometimes the container does not get updated with the latest packages, so the above steps make sure that the container can get updated packages.

Comment: This worked thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install express

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8085

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while following Net Ninja Docker tutorial.  Finally fixed problem when I realized the package.json file was not in the same directory as the Dockerfile.  When I moved the package.json file to the same directory, the Docker image build was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. In my case it was like this

```
RUN npm i nodemon
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app
```

So basically what I had to do was to add -global parameter to the install instruction.

```
RUN npm i -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more step before "npm install" -

```
RUN apk update && apk add npm
```