# Errors witn npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am migrating to a new (virtual) Windows 10 machine, and have got to the stage of installing Electron.

I have successfully installed node.js (node-v16.16.0-x64.msi) into `C:\Program Files` and now have a `cmd` prompt.

When I run

```bash
npm update npm
```

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-21T05_48_27_188Z-debug-0.log
```

I get the same error if I try installing anything with `npm`, but this is the same problem after a fresh install.

Is there a bug with `npm` or is there something magical I’m not doing right?

Comment: `node -v; npm -v; which node; which npm;`?

Comment: Did you do this: "Run the downloaded Node.js .msi Installer - including accepting the license, selecting the destination, and authenticating for the install."?

Comment: @JBallin `node -v`:` v16.16.0`;  `npm -v`: `npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use --location=global instead. 8.11.0`; Windows doesn’t have `which`, but this is a fresh install.

Comment: @JBallin I did, and the fact that `npm` gives me any messages at all suggest that Node and npm were installed.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: `npm config list`? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-config

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists while creating the Docker image for Node project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534295/npm-err-tracker-idealtree-already-exists-while-creating-the-docker-image-for)

Comment: Why does user agent show other node and npm versions?

Comment: You don't need to update npm. What task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I was in the wrong virtual machine. the correct config only has the following uncommented: `prefix = "C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"`. I don’t need to update npm, but I was testing npm after several other failed attempts. I am really trying to install electron-builder.

Comment: You're trying to install the pkg within a folder that has a package.json, right? Can you show the output of what happens when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the version problem of NPM. if you are using windows then you can follow this:

1. Go to folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. You have to edit four files named `npm`, `npm.cmd`, `npx`, `npx.cmd`
3. Open the files in a text editor, like Visual Studio Code
4. Replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global` in all four files
5. After this Run this command

   `npm i latest-version`

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and then running npm install?

Comment: I made changes you mentioned. I can successfully install `electron-builder` with `npm install -g electron-builder`, but running your last command gives me a -4071 error: `EINVAL: invalid argument, rename '…' -> '…'`.